# NodeJS HTTP request POST ERROR socket hang up

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, rest

Hi I'm having problems to perform HTTP request on NodeJS given a larger number array of json object. The request works fine given small array of json object. However, if I try to increase the size array of json, I received Error: socket hang up {"error":{"code":"ECONNRESET"}}. Is it required to perform multiple write? Or is it something wrong going on at the other end?

Thanks in advance for taking your time here!

```
    // data is a json object

    var post_data = JSON.stringify(data);
    var buf = new Buffer(post_data);
    var len = buf.length;

    var options = {
        hostname: address,
        port: port,
        path: pathName,
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Content-Length': len,
            'Transfer-Encoding':'chunked'
        }
    };

    // http call to REST API server
    var req = restHttp.request(options, function(res) {

        console.log('server PUT response received.');
        var resData = '';
        res.on('data', function(replyData) {

            // Check reply data for error.
            console.log(replyData.toString('utf8'));
            if(replyData !== 'undefined')
                resData += replyData;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {          
            callback(JSON.parse(resData));
        });
    }); 


    req.write(buf);
    req.end();
```

Comment: You can stream the request body. Read [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-streams/) post for the details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So this is an issue related to the streaming? Could u provide an example how it could apply in this situation?

Comment: if the data in `buf` was in a [readable stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) then you can just do `buf.pipe(req)`. For example, if the current directory contains a file `data.json` with the JSON you can do `var buf = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/data.json');` to create a `ReadStream` object. Then you can pipe this to you req.

Comment: Update: buf is a Buffer object. Could you provide the example as an answer so that I could give you credit for this help :) Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. I added the answer below :)

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? I have similar issue though I am not sending data from a buffer, but rather as application/x-www-form-urlencoded so it is all in encoded string...

Comment: Hi Daniel, which version of nodejs are u using?

Answer (score 2):

You can stream the request body.

If the data in `buf` was in a [readable stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) then you can just do `buf.pipe(req)`.

For example, if the current directory contains a file `data.json` with the JSON you can do

```
var buf = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/data.json');
```

to create a ReadStream object. Then you can pipe this to you req

```
buf.pipe(req);
```

The pipe command will call `req.end` once its done streaming.